# Two ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, ping, network-interface, network-connection

I have mounted two ethernet adapter on my pc and each of them has connected to a seperate network. The problem is that only one of them is active at a same time. In other verb I can ping only through one of them at the same time and if l want to ping another network l should disable the first adapter. So now l want to know how can I use both of them same time.

Comment: What ips assigned to adapters?

Comment: 192.168.0.16 and 192.168.0.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid assigning multiple adapters in the same computer to the same subnet.When configuring multiple NICs, each NIC should communicate with a different subnet. Configuring two or more NICs on the same subnet may cause communication problems. Delve deeper in [this](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/12558/en/) article. There're also example scenarios using two adapters

Also you just can assign 192.168.0.16 to the first adapter, and 192.168.1.16 to another